# How to control the print order from 2 different threads in rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, stdout

I'm writing a small program that deploys 2 threads, a sender thread that prompts for user input and a receiver thread that receives the input as a message and prints it out to the standard output.

A simple run should look like this:

```bash
> hello
< hello
```

but instead, using the following code example, it ends up looking like this:

```bash
> hello
> < hello
```

Here is the code:

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;

fn main() {
    let mut threads = vec![];
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::sync_channel(1);

    // Sender
    threads.push(thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            let mut input = String::new();

            print!("> ");
            io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
            io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
            tx.send(input).unwrap();
        }
    }));

    // Receiver
    threads.push(thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            let message = rx.recv().unwrap();
            println!("< {message}");
        }
    }));

    for thread in threads {
        thread.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

My assumption is that when the receiver gets to `println!("< {message}")` the sender already got to the next `print!("> ")` and both strings are flushed together in the wrong order, what is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @drewtato's solution which works well, I found the `Barrier` sync primitive which seems a bit more straight forward.

In the main function, define the barrier:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut threads = vec![];
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::sync_channel(1);
    let barrier = Arc::new(Barrier::new(2));
    let tx_block = Arc::clone(&barrier);
    let rx_block = Arc::clone(&barrier);

    /* spawn the threads ... */
}
```

then the sender thread after sending waits for the receiver to finish:

```rust
// sender
tx.send(input).unwrap();
tx_block.wait();  // wait for the receiver to finish
```

and the receiver wakes up the sender once finishing:

```rust
// receiver
println!("< {message}");
rx_block.wait();  // finished, wake up the sender
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create another channel to send a message back when the receiver is done printing, and then send the sender half through the channel with the message.

In the second channel, the message type is `()`, the unit type, which contains no data.

```rs
// sender
let (unwaiter, waiter) = mpsc::sync_channel(0);
tx.send((input, unwaiter)).unwrap();
waiter.recv().unwrap();
```

```rs
// receiver
let (message, unwaiter) = rx.recv().unwrap();
println!("< {message}");
unwaiter.send(()).unwrap();
```

Comment: +1 for creativity :), isn't this overkill though? I was thinking about a mutex but trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: @ShlomoGottlieb maybe, but both ends need ownership somehow, which the channel handles, and I checked the source and a zero-length sync channel is already a mutex internally. If you want something more well-suited, there's [oneshot](https://docs.rs/oneshot/).